# How to install wheel packages

Tags: python-2.7, python-wheel

I am trying to install PocketSphinx in Python. I am trying to follow the [Uberi speech recognition README](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#readme), which asks the following:

> PyAudio [wheel packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) for
>   common 64-bit Python versions on Windows and Linux are included for
>   convenience, under the `third-party/`
>   [directory](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/third-party)
>   in the repository root. To install, simply run `pip install wheel`
>   followed by `pip install ./third-party/WHEEL_FILENAME` (replace `pip`
>   with `pip3` if using Python 3) in the repository [root
>   directory](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition).

I do not understand the instruction here. What `FILE_NAME` is this referring to? What is this `wheel` and how does it relate to PocketSphinx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you downloaded the PocketSphinx package manually, it must have created a wheel file (the file which does the real job) with a `.whl` extension in the said directory.

Now, you need to open a terminal in the directory where the `.whl` extension file is stored, which in this case is `third-party`.

Once you make sure that the terminal shows the current directory as `third-party`, go ahead and do a pip install of the wheel file.

Assuming the name of the wheel file to be `PocketSphinx.whl`,

You'd write:

```
pip install PocketSphinx.whl
```

This will do your job if all requirements are met.

And I have a feeling that the name of the wheel file wouldn't be simply `PocketSphinx.whl`, it'll be long and informative, nonetheless it will always have the extension `.whl`, by which you shall identify it.

**Edit:**

I went to the link you provided, and this is the wheel file you need:

`pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` for python 3.5

Or

`pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` for python 2.7

So your command becomes

```
pip install pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Or

```
pip install pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

As per your python version.

Answer (score 0):

> What FILE_NAME is this referring to?

Filename of the binary package file in `third-party` folder of the repository. For example [pocketsphinx-0.0.9-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/third-party/pocketsphinx-0.0.9-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl). You are supposed to checkout repository first.

> What is this 'wheel' and how does it relate to pocketsphix?

wheel is a python package manager to install binary packages. It is used to install python binary package. You can read more here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel